# Backup all home folders on usb disk and accessibility

Tags: usb, backup, disk, multiple-users

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and have multiple family members working on it, each with their own home folder.

I have an USB disk that I want to use to backup all my home folders.

- When my disk auto mounts, it is not visible for every user. It seems to be visible only for the active user at the time I connect the usb disk.
- I want to create one folder per home on the usb disk to backup the data to. But when I format the disk in EXT4 or FAT for example it is Read Only. How can I format the disk so it is accessible to every user.

Best Regards, Patrick

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having isn't related to the file system you are putting on the disk, it's related to how you are mounting it. If you want all users to be able to use the disk I suggest you mount the entire disk at system boot in by editing /etc/fstab or partition the disk with separate backup partitions for each user and mount those partitions by editing /etc/fstab. Permissions to read and write to the mount points you use can be handled by adjusting permissions at the mount point. If don't want everyone to have access to all the data, the separate partition per user, each with it's own mount point seems simplest. For more information on system wide mounting, please see [this.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Systemwide_Mounts)

If something is unclear and you need further assistance, drop me a comment and I'll do my best to clarify the answer.